# Directed join of open sets in a topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{ A_i \mid i \in I \}$ be a collection of open sets in some topological space $\mathcal{X}$ such that for all $i, j \in I$ there exists a $k \in I$ such that $A_i \cup A_j \subseteq A_k$. Is it true that $\bigcup \{ A_i \mid i \in I \} \in \{ A_i \mid i \in I \}$?

**Edit:** what if we assume $\mathcal{X}$ to be compact Hausdorff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and consider $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}_+$. Then define

$$A_i=(0, i)\mbox{ for }i\in I$$

Obviously $A_i\subseteq A_j$ if $i\leq j$ and so the assumption $A_i\cup A_j\subseteq A_k$ is trivially satisfied for $k=\max(i, j)$.

Note that

$$\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i=\big(0,\sup(I)\big)$$

which is not in $\{A_i\}$ if $\sup(I)\not\in I$. E.g. this fails for $I=(0,1)$.

Comment: What if $\mathcal{X}$ is compact Hausdorff?

Comment: @MathStudent020 It still fails. Take $X=[0,1]$, $I=(0,\frac{1}{2})$ in my example. Arguments from my answer are still valid.

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $X= \mathbb R$ with the usual topology ,

let $I= \mathbb N$ and for $i \in I$ let $A_i$ be the open intervall $(-i,i)$.

Then

$A_i \cup A_j =A_{\max \{i,j\}}$,

$\bigcup \{ A_i \mid i \in I \}= \mathbb R$,

but $ \mathbb R \notin \{ A_i \mid i \in I \}$.